# Robocopied files show in CMD but not in Explorer

Tags: windows, robocopy

I'm helping a friend to setup a back drive on his W7 machine. I installed a new hard drive internally to serve as a backup.

I then wrote a simple `script.bat` that lives in his home folder, to be executed as a task.

From memory, I don't have the machine in front of me:

```
robocopy /S C:\Documents M:\Backup
```

The task is a running as administrator. This didn't work until I set a password on the admin account. The task is run every logon.

The backup copy works correctly and I can see new and newly modified Word files in `M:\Backup` via `cmd`. I cannot however see them in Explorer. I can see the drive, `M:`, but no folders or files. **

I suspected permissions. I thus took ownership of the whole drive and changed permissions to allow everything ( not what I really want in the end, just read would be best ).

Still can see via `cmd` but not in Explorer. For my friend that is not helpful.

I do not have the machine in front of me now so It's difficult to recall all details. I'll try to take screen shots when I can of how I'm running the task. He is very low income and has a dail-up connection (!) and internet is painful to use to anything but ASCII email.

I'm not a windows guy either so I could be doing something stoopid. 
If you ask for clarification or more details in the comments I'll update asap.

**correction:

I can see the the root folder `M:\Backups` but not the contents of `Backups`

Comment: Perhaps try mounting A: as something else. Windows/old tools behave strangely with drives A: and B:.

Comment: Switched to letter M but no love.

Comment: `I can see the the root folder M:\Backups` Is that a typo - you have it as `Backup` (with no `s`) elsewhere. Also, have you tried running Explorer as-admin?

Comment: Yes a typo. I'm using admin acct but didn't do any other explicit as admin action with Explorer.

Answer (score 1):

there are two possible areas - the robocopy has other flags, use copy:DT to only copy the data and timestamps and not the acl infomation from the source directory

It could also be with the M:\ make a sub-folder called X and change to M:\X\ for destination.
If still persists, right click the X folder and look at properties to see if it is "hidden"