# Folder not visible in Explorer or from cmd after RoboCopy

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, robocopy

I use RoboCopy to do a basic backup of one of my (non-OS) HDD's:

```
robocopy D:\ X:\Backup\D /MIR /XD D:\ExcludeMe
```

The destination directory (X:\Backup\D) had not been created before execution.

After the script is run, the data has been copied, but the folder (x:\Backup\D) is not visible in Explorer, or via cmd (`dir`).

If I navigate directly to it, through either the address bar in explorer, or through `cd` in cmd, I can get there and the folders within are visible.

[Here is a slightly similar question](https://superuser.com/questions/1028513/robocopied-files-show-in-cmd-but-not-in-explorer), which suggests only copying data and timestamps using /copy:DT. However, I've just tried this and it doesn't seem to work.

Any ideas why this might be the case?

Comment: Sounds like it may be related to security attributes and such. Look over the options for RC and see what it says about security and copying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Robocopy gotcha when copying from a root directory

This can happen when running robocopy to copy a root directory, as it may set the directory attributes to hidden.
The following command, as per https://serverfault.com/a/455029/399723 will fix this:

```
attrib -h -s X:\Backup\D
```

Alternatively, adding the `/A-:SH` switch to ignore system files when copying may prevent the directory from becoming hidden in the first place, as per https://serverfault.com/a/565804/399723.

`robocopy D:\ X:\Backup\D /MIR /XD D:\ExcludeMe /A-:SH`